# Is it possible to add horizontal range slider control for line charts on x-axis to control x-axis data dynamicaly using chartJS

Tags: chart.js

I am using Angular7 and ChartJS for to create multiline chart and I have to control the chart data using horizontal range slider on x-axis. When I move the range slider the chart data should vary according to the range slider and chart should be displayed. Is it possible using chartJS?

Example: I have 6 months data should be displayed on chart and when I move the slider on x-axis to 3 months or 4 months then accordingly the charts data should be displayed along with x-axis labels.